# Unity custom UI Messagebox

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a custom messagebox to display text that characters say throughout my game. I tried to achieve this through this code:

```
[SerializeField] public Text PresetText;
[SerializeField] public GameObject PresetBorder;
[SerializeField] public GameObject Canvas;

private Text UIText;

private Text _tempText;
private GameObject _tempBorder;

public static bool TEXT_INPUT;

public string text = "Placeholder.";

void Start ()
{
    _tempBorder = Instantiate(PresetBorder as GameObject);
    _tempBorder.transform.SetParent(Canvas.gameObject.transform, false);


    _tempText = Instantiate(PresetText) as Text;
    _tempText.transform.SetParent(Canvas.gameObject.transform, false);

    UIText = _tempText;
    UIText.text = text;
}
public void SetText ( string _text )
{
    text = "Speech: " + _text;
}
void Update ()
{
    UIText.text = text;
}
```

... and I am calling the SetText () function through this in a dummy file:

```
public MessageShell m;
void Start ()
{
    m.SetText("Test!");
}
```

(MessageShell because my code file is named MessageShell.cs)

The problem is if I call this, an empty border with no text appears. How do I fix this and could I improve this script?

Comment: May check with this code in Start() `m = GetComponent<MessageShell>(); m.SetText("Test");`

Comment: Just FTR Ian.  Really, perhaps just do this using the graphical interface in the editor.  I mean it's only a text field - just put it in your preload scene (or whatever), mark as DonotDestroyOnLoad and then you can set the value and/or hide it throughout your game play.  After all it's the whole point of having an IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that I would do is to figure out where the problem lies. Is the text created? Where does it actually appear? Run the game, and look at the game object view to see what is happening for these objects.

My second observation is that you probably want the text to be parented to the border. This allows the border to adequately manage the text, and how it laid out. They should go together.

Lastly, take a look at LayoutGroups. If your border has a layout group, then it should adjust it's size (Or adjust the size of it's children) to match the text as you want it to be.

Comment: Jup, the text is created. The problem is that the `string text` apparently is never modified, because if I set it manually in the inspector it stays empty.

Comment: Just found out why it was empty: The `string text` was public, and moreover empty in the inspector. The method SetText() still doesnt work though. Any ideas how I could fix this?

Comment: What is attached to m?

Comment: I suspect that m isn't fully set up correctly, that it isn't connected to the object you are seeing in your hierachy.